# выравнивание по горизонтали по центру Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap4

есть строка то есть row в нее есть 2 элемента "col-lg-3" и "col-lg-5 ml-auto"
после уменьшения экрана  "col-lg-5 ml-auto" переходит на другую строку
хочу этот элемент который уже на 2 строке выровнять по центру
вопрос:
почему justify-content: center; не работает
 а text-align: center; работает

Comment: Просто приведите свой код, не надо описывать его словами.

Comment: `justify-content` - Определяет, как браузер распределяет пространство вокруг флекс-элементов вдоль главной оси контейнера. `text-align` - свойство описывает, как линейное содержимое, наподобие текста, выравнивается в блоке его родительского элемента.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй  margin: 0 auto должно сработать

Comment: Это рабочий способ для plain html... но у автора фреймворк.

Comment: тоже не работает только text-align  работает